# How to add for loop values into a vector

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, vector

I have made following for loop and i got 10 values, but i need to transfer those values into a vector. How can i do it? I need to box plot those values.

```
oma <- function(y){ 
  x <- 6.1
  (x^y*exp(-x))/funktio(y)
}
oma(10)

y <- 1:10

for(i in y)
  print(oma(i))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
result = numeric(length = 10)
## only good if `y` is of the form `1:n`
for (i in y) {
  result[i] = oma(i)
}


## Safer version, works even if `y` doesn't start at 1 and increment by 1
result = numeric(length = length(y))
for (i in seq_along(y)) {
  result[i] = oma(y[i])
}
```

Everything you do in `oma` is vectorzied, so if `funktio` is also vectorized you could go directly to `result = oma(y)` without a loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sapply` :

```
vec <- sapply(y, oma)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `lapply`

```
vec <- unlist(lapply(y, oma))
```